# If $h(x) = 7 + 6f(x)$ , where $f(5) = 7$ and $f '(5) = 2$, find $h'(5)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've tried to take the derivative of $h(x)$, but this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: $h'(x)=6f'(x) \implies h'(5)=6f'(5)=...$

Comment: $f'(5)=6\cdot 2=12$.

Answer (score 1):

We just need to take derivative to obtain

$$h’(x)=0+6f’(x)\implies h’(5)=6f’(5)$$